# Difference between “tu” and “toi”

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels

When I translate “toi” and “tu”, I find that both mean “you”. What is the difference between them? When do we use each?

Comment: I know you can say: 'Toi et Alex, (est-ce que) vous avez visité Paris?'(= Have you and Alex visited Paris?), in a question with 2 subjects, but can you say 'Est-ce que tu et Alex avez visité Paris?' OR 'Est-ce que toi et Alex avez visité Paris?'

Answer (score 22):

In English *you* is used as subject and object personal pronoun but in French we use different words accordingly.

***Tu*** is always subject:

> Tu parles.
>   Où vas-tu ?
>   Que manges-tu ?

***Te*** is always object:

- Direct object:

  > Je te vois.
  >   Je t'aime. (note the elision in front of the vowel)
- Or indirect object:

  > Je te donne un livre.
  >   Je te pose une question.
  >   Te plaît-il ?

***Toi*** can be:

- Indirect object when the object is placed after the verb:

> Je donne un bonbon à toi et un gâteau à ton frère.
>   Je viens vers toi.
>   Je commence par toi.

Subject in specific constructions when we want to emphasize on the subject:

> Je prends le croissant et toi la brioche.
>   Toi, tu as l'air fatigué.
>   J'ai faim, et toi?
>   Toi, viens ici !
>   C'est toi.

It must be used after an imperative, with reflexive verbs:

> Depêche-toi.
>   Lave-toi.

Comment: Wouldn't "te" in "Te plaît-il?" be an indirect object, since we would say "Il plaît À la fille" (whereas you would still say "Il voit la fille"). I think the "Te plaît-il?" construction is analogous to the German "Gefällt er dir?"

Comment: @TheThunderChimp  Yes you're quite right - I did not put it in the right paragraph. Well spotted.Thanks.

Comment: il manque l'élision. "Je donne un bonbon à toi" est incorrecte.

Answer (score 10):

I am french so I hope my English won't be bad.
Well, in french "toi" is used when you refer directly to the person you are talking to, whereas "tu" is always followed by a verb.
Voilà!

Comment: *Followed* (suivre) n'est pas le mot qui convient ici. Dans une question *tu* peut-être après le verbe !

Comment: _Followed_ ici est bien utilisé.Certes, mais ce que @user5491 voulait probablement dire c'est qu'il y a forcément un verbe _non loin du sujet_ "tu".